# Limit options of Django ManytoManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have an app that has 3 models: Podcasts, Episodes, and Categories.

Categories have a ForeignKey for Podcast:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...
    podcast = models.ForeignKey(Podcast, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

So, a podcast can have a bunch of associated categories.

Each episode can be associated with a podcast's category. I've added that as a ManyToManyField:

```
class Episode(models.Model):

    podcast = models.ForeignKey(Podcast, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    ...
```

The problem is, in the admin, and modelforms, the categories field shows a list of every category for every podcast, not just the ones associated to this podcast.

How can I use limit_choices_to to only limit categories with the foreign key of the same podcast the episode is related to?  I've tried the following, but obviously doesn't work because 'self' is not defined.

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, limit_choices_to={'podcast': self.podcast})
```

I'd like to do this at the model level if possible so I dont have to add additional logic around the rest of the app.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like the case when you would normally want to use ManyToMany relationship with an intermediate model (Podcast in this case). Unless you have to keep your relations as they are, consider this solution:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)


class Episode(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='Podcast')


class Podcast(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    episode = models.ForeignKey(Episode, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: The issue here seems to be that a podcast can have multiple categories.  A podcast can have multiple categories, but a category can only have one podcast.  An episode can have multiple categories, and categories can have multiple episodes. But episodes and categories must have the same podcast.

Comment: You think instances of Category and Episode models with m2m relationship will refer to different Podcast instances - is that right? You create m2m relationship between them through an intermediate model by creating new instances of this intermediate model. Take a look at the example in the docs.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but what I'm saying is in the model above, it looks like Podcast (which is a collection of episodes), can only be associated with ONE episode, because it's a foreign key on the Podcast model. And also only be associated with ONE category. am i reading that wrong?

Comment: ForeignKey is one-to-many relationship, so here one Podcast instance can be related to many Category and Episode instances. Which is what you would normally want, I think.